# how to have a list of TextEditingController for one TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working with a stateful widget and created a list inside initstate but whenever I test and try to print the value of even the first controller.text either I get this error

> Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

or a null I already posted my issue 3 times in different manners, still no workable solution, any help please !

```
class AnswerQuizPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnswerQuizPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AnswerQuizPage> createState() => _AnswerQuizPageState();
}

class _AnswerQuizPageState extends State<AnswerQuizPage> {
  int? _numPages ;
  int _currentPage = 1;
  bool test=false;
  bool colorchoice=false;
  var questionController= QuestionController(QuestionRepositoryImpl());
  List<String> reponse=[];
  List<String> asnwers=[];
  List<TextEditingController>_reponse=[];
  List<TextEditingController> _controllers = [];
  List<TextEditingController> controllers = [];
  List<QuestionModel> listofquestion=[];
  List<QuizQuestion> listofquizquestionsforquiz=GlobalParams.quizmodel.quizQuestions;
  @override
  List<dynamic> trList=[];
  GlobalKey<FormState> globalFormKey=GlobalKey<FormState>();
  void show(){
    List<TextEditingController> _controllers2=[];
    String test;
    GlobalParams.quizmodel.quizQuestions.forEach((element) { final   quantityController =
    TextEditingController(text: element.userAnswer);
    controllers.add(quantityController);
    reponse.add(element.userAnswer);
    });
  }
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
show();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(GlobalParams.quizmodel.id);
    Future<List<QuestionModel>> quizlist=questionController.getQuestionsByQuizId(GlobalParams.quizmodel.id);
    quizlist.then((value)  {
      listofquestion=value;
    });
    _numPages=listofquestion.length;
    int? idtochoose;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        title:Text('répondre au quiz'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          //login
          Container(

            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              //color: Colors.orange[600],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0, top:5.0, bottom: 5.0,),
            child: Tooltip(
              message: "vous devez finir le quiz",
              child: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
            ),
          ),


        ],

      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(50),
        child: FutureBuilder<List<QuestionModel>>(
    future:questionController.getQuestionsByQuizId(GlobalParams.quizmodel.id),
    builder:(context ,snapshot){
    if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting){
    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
    }
    if (snapshot.hasError){
    print('${snapshot.error}');
    print('${snapshot}');

    return Center(child: Text('${snapshot}'),);
    }
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(child: buildBodyContent(snapshot, questionController)),
       /* QuizQuestionTextControllerWidget(controllers: _controllers, listofquizquestions: GlobalParams.quizmodel.quizQuestions, reponse: reponse),*/
        SizedBox(height: 50,),
        Container(
          child: FormHelper.submitButton("Ajouter", () async{


            print('hello');
            print('${GlobalParams.quizmodel.id}');
            print('${GlobalParams.quizmodel.quizQuestions[0].quizquestionpk.idQuestion}');
           
            for (var j=0;j<_controllers.length;j++){
              print('${_controllers[j].text}');
            }
            for (var j=0;j<reponse.length;j++){
              print(j);
              print('${reponse[j]}');
            }

            print(controllers[0].text);

          },
            btnColor: Colors.blue,
            borderColor: Colors.white,
            txtColor: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: 10,),
        ),

      ],
    );

    },
    ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

SafeArea buildBodyContent (AsyncSnapshot <List<QuestionModel>> snapshot,
    QuestionController questionController){
  bool colorchoice=false;
  Color colorDet;
 List <String> reponse=[];
  List<String> asnwers=[];
 List<QuizQuestion> listofquizquestions=GlobalParams.quizmodel.quizQuestions;
 List<TextEditingController> controllers=[];
 // List<TextEditingController> _reponse=[];
  List<TextEditingController> _controllers = [];
 int idx;

 GlobalParams.quizmodel.quizQuestions.forEach((element) { final   quantityController =
 TextEditingController(text: element.userAnswer);
 controllers.add(quantityController);
 });
  return SafeArea(
    child:
    Scrollbar(
      isAlwaysShown: true,
      thickness: 5,
     // scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.,
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context,index)
          {
            var cq=snapshot.data?[index];
            controllers.add( TextEditingController());

            return Column(
              children:[
                SizedBox(height: 10,),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:5.0, bottom: 5.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Text(cq!.enonce, style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,

                      ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Text(
                        'réponse a : ${cq.propositionA}', style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,

                      ),),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Text(
                        'réponse b : ${cq.propositionB}', style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,

                      ),),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Text(
                        'réponse c : ${cq.propositionC}', style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,

                      ),),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Container(

                        child: InkWell(

                          onTap: (){
                            colorchoice=!colorchoice;
                            if(colorchoice){
                              colorDet = Colors.green;
                            }
                            else {
                              colorDet= Colors.orange;
                            }
                          },

                          child: Text(
                            'réponse d : ${cq.propositionD}', style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,

                          ),),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10,),
              
                        Column(

                          children: [
                            TextFormField(
                            controller: controllers[index],
                            //onEditingComplete: (text) {  print('First text field: $text');  },
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: ' réponse',
                            ),
                            validator: (value){
                              if (value!.isNotEmpty){
                                // _controllers.add(_controllers[index]);
                                print('${controllers[index].text}');

                                //asnwers.add(asnwers[index]);
                                // tr="QUATRE_A_CINQ";
                                return null;
                              } else {
                                return "libelle ne peut pas être vide";
                              }
                            },
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      ),
                          ],
                        ),
                   /* })
                  ],
                ),*/
                SizedBox(height: 10,),
              ],
            );
          },
          itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ??0),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the issue is there is no data on list but you are calling first index

Comment: I added my code in the pub, please check

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution it might work for you.

Replace this

```
controllers.add(TextEditingController());
```

with

```
controllers.clear();
snapshot.data?.forEach((element) {
              controllers.add(TextEditingController());
            });
```